# Unable to capture screenshot using ExtentReport version 4-- Selenium-Java

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Unable to capture a screenshot using extent report 4(Selenium-Java)
Error msg is :-
**FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown([TestResult name=expediaTitleCheck status=FAILURE method=Expedia_TC.expediaTitleCheck()[pri:0, instance:com.extent.testcases.Expedia_TC@72b6cbcc] output={null}])**
**Code is as follows:-**

```
public class Expedia_TC {
    WebDriver driver;
    Expedia exp;
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReport;
    ExtentReports extent;
    ExtentTest test;

    @BeforeTest
    public void startBrowser() {
        htmlReport = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Reports/ExpediaReport.html");
        htmlReport.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
        htmlReport.config().setDocumentTitle("Expedia Automation Report");
        htmlReport.config().setReportName("Functional Report");
        htmlReport.config().setTimeStampFormat("EEEE,DD-MM-YYYY,hh:mm:ss");
        htmlReport.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReport); 
        extent.setSystemInfo("OS","Windows10");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment","Production");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Tester","Jayashree");

        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"/dev/null");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        exp = new Expedia(driver);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void expediaTitleCheck() {
        test = extent.createTest("Title Check Test...");
        exp.checkPageTitle();
        test.fail("This Test is Failed!");

    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result)throws IOException {
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            String methodName ="<b>"+result.getMethod().getMethodName()+" : "+"FAILED"+"</b>";
            String errorMsg = "<b>"+"REASON: "+" "+result.getThrowable().getMessage()+"</b>";
            String failureScreenshot = Expedia_TC.captureScreen(driver, methodName);
            test.log(Status.FAIL,MarkupHelper.createLabel(methodName,ExtentColor.RED));
            test.log(Status.FAIL,errorMsg);
            try {
            test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(failureScreenshot);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}


    @AfterTest
    public void endReport() {
        extent.flush();
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: what is the version of extent report. I suggest to use the latest version available.

Comment: I am using extent report version  4.0.9